# How to use pdo in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

As I know PDO support has been added to codeigniter recently but I can't find any documentation or tutorial about how to actually use it. Can anyone tell how can I use it?

Comment: Whats about `$pdo = new PDO($dsn)`? http://php.net/pdo.construct

Comment: Op hasn't done 1 bit of search i can tell that perfectly. I just typed in google 'codeigniter pdo' and voila! The 1st link is the answer! I could have put here but then.... I don't appreciate spoon feeding. Google those term and 1st link is the tutorial you searched for. Plus that article also describes how to store session in database through pdo by codeigniter.

Comment: It would be much better if you had read the article itself not the title only. It's written in March 31, 2011, while codeigniter 2.1 with native support of pdo was released in november 2011. I haven't fully read the article myself but why would I need to copy some class and hack ci native libraries if it already supports pdo???

Answer (score 3):

You can edit `/application/config/database.php` and to enable the PDO driver:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'pgsql:localhost'; 
// or mysql:localhost
// or sqlite::memory:
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
```

If you want to directly get you hand on the active DB connection. This might work, but I am not CI developer .. so no guarantees. I tried to understand that **brain rotting code**, but i suspect, that i failed. I'm not good at PHP4 + `eval()`:

```
$CI = get_instance();
var_dump($CI->db->conn_id);
// should show that conn_id is instance of PDO
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, since CodeIgniter is merely a PHP framework, nothing prevents you from using it natively, as in `$pdo = new PDO(...);`.

However, when they say PDO is now supported, I think they mean their normal `Database` class now uses PDO (rather than MySQLi or the such).