# Codeigniter Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string():

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-real-escape-string

Got below error while using codigniter 3.0

```
FYI using PHP Version 5.5.12,Apache Version Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated
>   and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
>
> Filename: models/common_model.php
>
> Line Number: 21
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\Codeigniter\application\models\common_model.php
>   Line: 21 Function: mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use PDO in codeigniter to solve all problem related to `mysql` and `mysqli`..

see how to use PDO in CI
if you are using CI 3 then http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

and if you are using CI 2.x
[How to use pdo in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861537/how-to-use-pdo-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Error Was Encountered

Invalid DB driver

Answer (score 6):

Go to `application => config => database.php` and change from

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

**Note** It is recommended to use [query builder class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) for queries.

Answer (score 5):

use `mysqli_real_escape_string();`

and replace `mysql` to `mysqli` in every functions.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Filename: models/common_model.php

Line Number: 21

Backtrace:

Comment: yes, first parameter should be link returned by ` mysqli_connect();`

Comment: sir in codigniter we add database in application/config/database.php so would their b link of database.....

Comment: yes, sorry, i didn't notice that, you have to change core file of CI where actual `mysql_connect()` is used, instead you can use PDO. just my another answer.